# How to split a df column according to customized string pattern?

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a dataframe like the below:

```
index      value
3          05/21
6          05/23
7         330433
9     05/2430366
11         30366
12         05/25
14         05/26
15         30366
17         05/27
18         30366
20         05/28
21         30366
23         05/29
24         30366
26         05/31
27         29933
```

I want to split it into two volumes:

```
0    1       2       
1  05/21    
2  05/23   330433
3  05/24    30366
4           30366
5  05/25    
6  05/26    30366
7  05/27    30366
8  05/28    30366
9  05/29    30366
10 05/31    29933
```

I have tried regex, but it does not work.

```
import regex as re
pat = '\*d{2}\/\d{2}\d*'
s1 = '05/2130366'
re.split(pat, s1)
```

I need some help, thank you.

Comment: Consider reimporting your data in the format you actually want to have.

Comment: @ERIC, so every non data data will come corresponding to the date data in the final table?

Comment: Also, I see one of the data as `05/2430366` is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: `data_dict = {
    'index':[3, 6, 7,9,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,23,24,26,27],
    'value': ['05/21', '05/23', '330433', '05/2430366', '30366', '05/25', '05/26', '30366', '05/27', '30366', '05/28', '30366', '05/29', '30366', '05/31', '29933']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the below code helps:

```
import regex as re
pat = '^(\d{0,2}\/\d{0,2})?'
s1 = '05/2130366'
s2 = '3456556'
s3 = '05/23'
```

Output:

```
>>> re.split(pat, s1)
['', '05/21', '30366']
>>> re.split(pat, s2)
['', None, '3456556']
>>> re.split(pat, s3)
['', '05/23', '']
```

Skip the first value, second & third values will be your required ones.